# Read API multipage PDF processing

Tags: ocr, azure-cognitive-services, vision-api

I've read compete documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-recognizing-text) and [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/2afb498089f74080d7ef85eb), and created dozen of examples but I still can't get if Read API process multi page PDF in parallel or in consecutive order?
If there is someone with good insight into this Azure service, please advise and share your experience with this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computer Vision [Read API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/2afb498089f74080d7ef85eb) process multiple page PDF in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, but where in documentation says so? How do you know? Have you tried it or you spoke with their support?

Comment: I've seen you edited your original answer. Would you please where and how "Computer vision product team" confirms parallel processing? Do you have link to the statement? Have you spoke with their support?

Comment: Yes we have checked with engineering team and they confirmed the same.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please point me in direction who to contact exactly? I need confirmation from MS team directly.

Comment: Hmm, Please raise a support ticket in the azure portal. https://ms.portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Support

Comment: Thank you. They confirmed what you said.